# Can't establish SSL connection to web service C#

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to connect to web-service. I'm new to SSL stuff. Here's my code:

```
public void SendRequest(string httpsUrl, string postData, String[] certificates, String password)
{
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(httpsUrl);

request.Method = "POST";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;


X509Certificate certificate = null;
foreach (String cert in certificates)
{
    certificate = new X509Certificate(cert, password);
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate); //add cert
}

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
}
```

The `request.GetRequestStream()` throws an exception: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

Certificates are given to me by the web service provider (.cer files), as well as password (key.dat), I think this might be my private key.

Any ideas why it throws this error? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it appears that remote server's certificate is invalid.